# Automating Model Builder (ArcMap) for NetCDF Processing

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, netcdf, climate, noaa

I have a NetCDF with 30+ years of monthly data from which I want to find the climatological normal. Using the NetCDF tutorial I found through NOAA (https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded_help/tools.html#arcgis in case anyone is interested), I discovered the Model Builder in ArcMap.

Is there anyway to have the model loop through each month's data to plug into the Raster Calculator so I can determine the climatological normal? I'd rather not have to build 360 branches manually. I can do this pretty easily in R, but I'm trying to expand my proficiency with Arc.

Comment: Cell Statistics may be what you're after https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000007q000000. Input all your years rasters then use statistic type of mean, median or majority to get the *average* over the last 30 years, each of these 3 statistic types could be considered average.. *but* you need to have a spatial analyst license to use this tool, do you have access to that extension?

Comment: @MichaelStimson I have the Spatial Analyst license. I’ll give Cell Stats a go.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, just wanted to let you know Cell Stats did exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's great, can you now answer your own question with detailed steps and some screen shots for the benefit of future readers of this post.